# Calling render() from a filter helper method in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, filter, dry

I have filters like the ones defined below. They run the same code block in various places, so to keep it DRY I refactored that code into a method called doResponse().

```
class MyFilters {

    def filters = {
        web(uri: '/web/**') {
            before = {

                // Do Stuff
                if (condition) {
                    doResponse(request, response, params)
                }
                return true
            }
            after = {
                if (condition) {
                    doResponse(request, response, params)
                }
                else {
                    // Do Stuff
                    doResponse(request, response, params)
                }

            }
            afterView = {
            }
        }
    }

    boolean doResponse(request, response, params) {
    // Do Stuff
        render(status: statusCode, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1", text: text)
    // Do post-render stuff
        return false
    }
}
```

However this has a nasty side effect. It seems that the render() method is only available from within the filters closure. Is there any (neat) way for me to call render() from doResponse()?

Edit: The error I get is:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyFilters.render() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[status:500, contentType:text/xml, encoding:ISO-8859-1, text:...]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the object that defines the `render(..)` method to the `doRespond(..)` method, and invoke the `render(..)` method on that object.

Closures have some [implicit variables](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-Implicitvariables), including their `owner` that refers to the parent closure; so we can pass that:

```
if (condition) {
    doResponse(owner, request, response, params)
}
```

`doRespond(..)` method:

```
boolean doResponse(webFilter, request, response, params) {
    // Do Stuff
    webFilter.render(status: statusCode, contentType: 
        "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1", text: text)
    // Do post-render stuff
    return false
}
```

Comment: hi I tried to do it, but getting: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'viewName' on null object
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass a reference to the `render` function to the `doResponse` function?

ie:

```
if( condition ) {
  doResponse(request, response, params, this.&render )
}
```

and

```
boolean doResponse( request, response, params, renderFn ) {
// Do Stuff
    renderFn( status: statusCode, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1", text: text )
// Do post-render stuff
    return false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that seems to be equivalent to calling render() directly from doResponse(). I get the same error.

Comment: Darn.  Out of interest, could you append the error you get to the question text?

Comment: Of course. It seems that SO snips the last parts of the exception text, but it should suffice.

Comment: So when you try the code above, you get the exact same error?  Or does it change to: `No signature of method: MyFilters.renderFn()` ?

Comment: Exactly the same, it still reports the error on render(), not renderFn()

Comment: Instead of `this.&render`, pass `owner.owner.&render` as we're within a nested closure (`this` means "this closure").

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution.

Change doResponse to a closure:

```
 def doResponse = {
        render(status: statusCode, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1", text: text)
        return false 
 }
```

Calling doResponse (from filter closure):

```
def doResponseClosure = doResponse.clone()
doResponseClosure.delegate = delegate
// if it doesn't work, try adding: doResponseClosure.owner = owner
return doResponseClosure()
```

The cloning is done because of concurrency reasons.

I've been using this method successfully in other Grails DSLs like Criteria closures.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but robbberts' solution requires slightly less code.